# When do extra hours count as overtime?

Tags: united-kingdom, overtime, leave

I work part-time (2.5 days a week) as a secretary for a small software company in Northern Ireland. Recently, I’ve been asked to work an extra two half days a week (3.5 days per week) to act in a different capacity as a sales administrator.

This extra work has only accepted on a verbal basis – there is nothing in writing, and no changes have been made to my contract. Is there are point at which extra hours are considered overtime, or are you entitled to additional leave?

Comment: You need to ask the person who asked you to work an extra two half days a week this question. Don't take anything verbally. Ask the person to send you an e-mail to explain the compensation for the extra work.

Comment: If NI also has a Citizen's Advice Bureau like the rest of the UK, you should talk to them. You should at least get paid the extra hours at your regular rate - I'm not sure how overtime rules work with part-time work in the UK.

Comment: How do you handle hours reporting right now? Do you have a time clock, a time reporting sheet, etc.? Did you ask your boss "where should I report the extra time" or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've decided the best course of action is to go with Snark Shark and HorusKol's suggestion and contact Citizen's Advice Bureau. As for hours reporting, there's nothing formal in place. My contract just states the days, start and end time I'm expected to work.

Comment: @nelb You may find that you're referred to HMRC.  I've added a couple of links into my answer below. See how you go with those.  You may need to contact Acas for advice as well.

Comment: Why did you accept to work extra time without asking if you'd be paid extra? What if the boss says "well, unfortunately there is no budget to pay you more, but you already said you could work the extra time..." Seeing as you work part-time, it's unlikely that the extra time will count as overtime. However for working extra you should be paid more (based on the number of hours you work, it sounds).

Comment: err no they are asking you to go from 2.5 days a week to 3.5 you should sign a variation of contract but you not going to be able to clame normal working hours as OT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your HR department.  They'll be able to define to your what constitutes overtime as regards to your contract and role.

This might also depend on how long these change in hours are likely to last.

See links on the gov.uk web site:

[Overtime Rights](https://www.gov.uk/overtime-your-rights)
and
[Pay and work rights helpline](https://www.gov.uk/pay-and-work-rights)

Comment: Unfortunately, being a small company, there is no HR department, just the boss. It sounds like you're say there is no overarching legal duty imposed on employers that defines a set limit on what is and is not considered overtime?

Comment: It sounds as though you'll need to consult with an external regulatory body (armed with your contract) to see how this affects your statutory rights as an employee.

Comment: @nelb yes but only for hours out side of the normal working week aka 9-5 you come across like your trying to scam your employer